# How to fix "Often Misused: Spring Remote Service"

Tags: fortify

I use Fortify for scanning code and got this problem by recommend

> **Recommendations:** *Utilize Spring Security and SSL to provide authentication, authorization, confidentiality and integrity.*

So I'm trying to fix this problem by implement Spring Security and basic authentication from the example guide 
http://www.jayway.com/2008/09/30/spring-remoting-with-security-and-ssl/

I will get spring configuration like this

**---- Server Side Configurations ---**

remote-server.xml

```
<bean name="/testService" class="org.springframework.remoting.caucho.HessianServiceExporter">
        <property name="service" ref="testService" />
        <property name="serviceInterface" value="example.TestService" />
</bean>
```

security-server.xml

```
<security:http auto-config="true">
    <security:http-basic/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />    
</security:http>
<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:user-service id="uds">
            <security:user name="testUser" password="testPassword" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_MANAGER" />
        </security:user-service>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

**--- Client Side Configurations ---**

remote-client.xml

```
<bean id="rcaRemotingService" class="org.springframework.remoting.caucho.HessianProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="serviceUrl" value="${endpoint.url}/testService"/>
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="example.TestService"/>
    <property name="username" value="${endpoint.user}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${endpoint.password}"/>
</bean>
```

But it doesn't work, the tools always hilight the problem like this

> **Abstract:** On line 5 of remoting-servlet.xml, the application exposes
>   spring beans as remote services. By default, these remote services do
>   not require authentication and information transferred to or from this
>   service is in clear text.   This could allow an attacker to access
>   privileged operations or expose sensitive data.
>
> **Sink:** **remote-server.xml:5** null()
>   *line 5:* <bean name="/testService" class="org.springframework.remoting.caucho.HessianServiceExporter">
>
> <property name="service" ref="testService" />
>
> <property name="serviceInterface" value="example.TestService" />
>
> </bean>